# Find differential equation with boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, weak-derivatives

Let $f \in C^0 (\Omega), g \in C^0 (\partial \Omega) $ and let $u \in C^2 (\overline{\Omega}) $ solve the equation
$$ \int_{\Omega} \langle \nabla u, \nabla w \rangle = \int_{\Omega} fw + \int_{\partial \Omega} gw \\ \forall w \in C^{\infty}_c (\Omega) $$

What could be a possible differential equation and its boundary conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example could be the following Poisson equation with inhomogeneous Neumann boundary condition:
\begin{aligned}
  -\Delta u &= f \, ,\\
  (\nabla u\cdot n)|_{\partial\Omega} &= g \, .
\end{aligned}
Indeed, using the relation $w \Delta u = \nabla\cdot(w \nabla u) - \nabla w\cdot \nabla u$ and the divergence theorem, one obtains the weak formulation
\begin{aligned}
  -\int_\Omega \Delta u\, w &= \int_\Omega \nabla w\cdot \nabla u - \int_\Omega \nabla\cdot(w \nabla u) \\
  &= \int_\Omega \nabla w\cdot \nabla u - \int_{\partial\Omega} w \nabla u\cdot n \\
  &= \int_\Omega \nabla w\cdot \nabla u - \int_{\partial\Omega} wg \\
  &= \int_\Omega fw\, .
\end{aligned}

Comment: Hi Harry49, thank you very much for this example! As well as for the proof, which I really appreciate! :-)